# Cannot display table record in html page

Tags: html, class, oop, pdo, record

I am trying to call a record from a table into html to create an admin page so the content can be updated. I cannot get the record to come up. I am totally new to this so any help is appreciated. My table name is tblContent and my database name is data1. I have only one row in the table with a PageID of 1.

home.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title><?php echo mysql_result($rs,0,”PageTitle”);?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="origstyle.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Site Heading</h1>

<?php

require_once 'classes.php';

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;db_name=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);
$rs = mysql_query("getData");
echo mysql_result($rs,0,”Content”);
} catch (PDOException $pe) {
die("Could not connect to the database $db_name :" . $pe->getMessage());
}



?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

classes.php

```
<?php 

//Enter your database connection details here.
$host = 'localhost'; //HOST NAME.
$db_name = 'XXXXdbName'; //Database Name
$db_username = 'XXXXuserName'; //Database Username
$db_password = 'XXXXpass'; //Database Password

try
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
exit('Error Connecting To DataBase');
}


class database
{
function __construct($pdo)
{
$this->pdo = $pdo;
}

function getData()
{
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data1');
$query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a lot of little issues that stop this code from working.

The biggest is that you are trying to use two different database libraries. There's the deprecated `mysql` library which has all the functions starting with `mysql_` and then there's PDO. Replace all the `mysql` functions with their `PDO` counterparts.

The next thing I notice is that you seem to be thinking that you pass a method name to the querying function (`mysql_query"myData"`), but you do not. You call the method on an instance of the class. First you create an instance, like you did for the PDO object, and then you call a method.

```
$database = new database()
$rs = $database->getData()
```

The third thing I noticed is that you are creating the PDO object twice. There's no need to create the instance in `home.php`, so just get rid of that (along with the try/catch stuff related to it).

The fourth thing is minor. You should also capitalize your class names.

Put these together, and you get something like this:

home.php:

```
require_once "classes.php";
$rs = $database->getData();
// Code that turns $rs into HTML
// Sorry, I don't know PDO well enough to
// say what that is.
// I do know that a simple echo will not suffice.
```

classes.php:

```
$host = "localhost"
$db_name = "";
$db_username = "";
$db_password = "";

class Database {
    function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    function getData () {
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data1');
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
}

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
} catch (PDOException e) {
    exit('Error Connecting To DataBase');
}

$database = new Database($pdo);
```